# Elasticsearch's minimumShouldMatch for each member of an array

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider an Elasticsearch entity:

```json
{
   "id": 123456,
   "keywords": ["apples", "bananas"]
}
```

Now, imagine I would like to find this entity by searching for `apple`.

```json
{
  "match" : {
    "keywords" : {
      "query" : "apple",
      "operator" : "AND",
      "minimum_should_match" : "75%"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `75%` minimum for matching would be required for both of the strings of the array – so nothing will be found. Is there a way to say something like `minimumSouldMatch: "75% of any array fields"`?

Note that I need to use `AND` as each item of `keywords` may be composed of longer text.

EDIT:

I tried the proposed solutions, but none of them was giving expected results. I guess the problem is that the text might be quite long, eg.:

`["national gallery in prague", "narodni galerie v praze"]`

I guess the fuzzy expansion is just not able to expand such long strings if you just start searching by "national g".

Would this may be be possible somehow via Nested objects?

```
{ keywords: [{keyword: "apples"}, {keyword: "babanas"}}
```

and then have `minimumShouldMatch=1` on keywords and then `75%` on each `keyword`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-boolean)

> The match query is of type boolean. It means that the text provided is analyzed and the analysis process constructs a boolean query from the provided text. The operator parameter can be set to or or and to control the boolean clauses (defaults to or). The minimum number of optional should clauses to match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

If you are searching for multiple tokens example "apples mangoes" and set minimum as  100%. It will mean both tokens should be present in document. If you set it at 50% , it means at least one of these should be present.

If you want to match tokens partially

You can use [fuzziness parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#match-field-params)

Using fuzziness you can set maximum edit distance allowed for matching

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "keywords": {
        "query": "apple",
        "fuzziness": "auto"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are trying to match word to its root form you can use ["stemming"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/stemming.html#stemming) token filter

```
PUT index-name
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "stemmer" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "keywords":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Tokens generated**

```
GET index-name/_analyze
{ 
   "text":  ["apples", "bananas"],
   "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}

"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "appl",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "banana",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 14,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 101
    }
  ]
```

stemming breaks words to their root form.

You can also explore n-grams, edge grams for partial matching

Comment: Please see the edits

Comment: @Vojtěch you cannot define 75% on each keyword. minimum should match is for minimum number of clauses  not for individual token. In case of match  it translates to minimum number of tokens it matches again not individual token.  are you looking for like %text% kind of functionality

Comment: `are you looking for like %text% kind of functionality` - yes this would be great

Comment: @Vojtěch check ngrams and wildcard in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070898/elasticsearch-searching-partial-text-in-string.